# LU decomposition with row pivoting

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Okay so consider a matrix 
$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$ 
so obviously to get the upper and lower traiangular matrix for LU factorization I first pivot and then eliminate so I get 
$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$  then making everything 0 under the diagonal I get the following

$$ U = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$ and 
$$ L = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Then since we pivoted we also get a permutation matrix $P$
$$ P = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

But if I try to go back using $A = P^TLU = (P^{-1}L)U$ I do not get my original matrix back. 
Note: the question is only asking to find the permutation matrix. I got the right permutation matrix and it matches the answer at the back of the book but I have a feeling I am just getting lucky.

Comment: "I do not get my original matrix back." - really? Could you show your multiplication and the result?

Comment: My mistake. How do iclose this without marking an answer

Comment: There should be a delete link below your question and above the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You considered the matrix $A$
$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$ 
and you multiplied by the matrix $P$ to get
$$ PA = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Your computations for $A$, $P$, $L$ and $U$ are right. Since $P = P^T = P^{-1}$ these are all the same. Computing the product $LU$ and $PA$ gives the same answer. I don't know what went wrong with your things.

Hope that helps! Sorry I couldn't say much more, but I think you just have to look at your computations.